# Как вырезать определенные ссылки из текста?

Tags: php

Есть некий список разрешенных ссылок, если они есть то нужно их найти и сделать активными, если ссылки нет в списке то нужно удалить ее. Пошаманил тут немного, вот что вышло

```
$text = 'привет, моя ссылка http://ya.ru, google.ru ну и www.site.org/page.php?id=133.';
$links = file('link.txt');

$regex = "/((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)?[a-z0-9\-]+(!?\.[a-z]{2,4}))/";
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $text_link);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($text_link[0]); $i++) {
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($links); $a++) {

        if (trim($text_link[0][$i]) == trim($links[$a])) {

            $text = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?' . trim($links[$a]) . '/',
                '<a href="' . $links[$a] . '">' . $links[$a] . '</a>', $text);
        } else {

            $text = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?' . trim($links[$a]) . '/',
                '[error]', $text);
        }
    }
}

echo $text;
```

работает оно не правильно, заменяет не так как нужно, помогите справиться с проблемой

Comment: Объясните что должно получаться, и расскажите что в файле `link.txt` находится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
$regex = "@(https?://)?(([a-z0-9.-]+)?[a-z0-9-]+(!?\.[a-z]{2,4}))@";
```

И подумайте на тему использовать [preg_ replace _callback](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$links = array(
        'ya.ru'         => "",
        'yandex.ru'     => "",
        'google.ru'     => "",
        'google.com'    => "",
);

function replace_link( $matches ) {
        global $links;

        if (isset($matches[2]) and !empty($matches[2])) {
                if (isset($links[$matches[2]])) {
                        $rc = '<a href="';
                        if (empty($matches[1])) {
                                $rc .= 'http://';
                        }
                        $rc .= $matches[0];
                        $rc .= '">';
                        $rc .= $matches[2];
                        if (isset($matches[3])) {
                                $rc .= $matches[3];
                        }
                        $rc .= '</a>';

                        $matches[0] = $rc;
                }
                else {
                        $matches[0] = "[error]";
                }
        }
        return $matches[0];
}

$text = 'привет, моя ссылка http://ya.ru, google.ru ну и www.site.org/page.php?id=133.';
$regex = "@(https?://)?([a-z0-9.-]{3,})(/[^\s]*)?@";

echo "Before:\n", $text, "\n";
$text = preg_replace_callback( $regex, 'replace_link', $text );
echo "After:\n", $text, "\n";
```

Comment: Столкнулся еще с такой проблемой, регулярка что вы привели не совсем правильно обрабатывает текст, если там будет английский текст то он тоже вырежет его как ссылку, еще кстати он не обрабатывает домены с кириллическими буквами типа домен.рф

Comment: Тогда определите что такое ссылка?
с доменом .рф тут тоже кое-какие заковырки имеются: очень хочется написать выражение: [а-я]+\.рф, но есть всякие прикольные имена типа www.домен.рф, тогда получается что нужно иметь что-то типа: ([0-9a-zа-я.-]*[0-9a-zа-я-]{2,}\.(?:[a-z]{2,4}|рф))

Comment: ссылка в моем понимании это нечто такое:
google.ru
http://google.ru
https://stat.google.ru
https://stat.google.ru/?page=1
и т.д.
навряд ли конечно удастся предусмотреть все варианты, но хотелось бы заставить работать хоть с такими.

Comment: В принципе можно взять список [TLD][1]
и написать:

    $regex = "@(https?://)?([0-9a-zа-я.-]{2,}\.(?:ru|com|тут все tld|рф)(/[^\s]*)?@iu";

Либо поискать что-то на [regexlib.com][2]

  [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains
  [2]:http://regexlib.com/